# Is it possible to get "Carte Object ID" in PDI Transformation step in Pentaho?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I would like to get the "Carte Object ID" in one of my kettle transformation step before to the mail sending step, in which I am sending this transformation status page URL as a link.

Below is the link I'm sending to the user from this transformation (using mail step at the end) in this I need to populate the Carte ObjectID

```
localhost:8080/pentaho/kettle/transStatus?name=?my_KTR?&id=?Carte Object ID?
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can get the Carte Object ID.

When you execute a transformation using the runTrans API you will be given an XML response that contains the Carte Object ID of the transformation.

You can also run the transStatus API with simply the name of the transformation you ran to find the Carte Object ID. Run the transStatus API like `localhost:8080/pentaho/kettle/transStatus/?name=<your-transformation's-name>&xml=y` and you will be returned an XML document that contains the Carte Object ID of that transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your response @eicherjc, I would like to get the Carte Object ID from one of my transformation step. I know we can get that id if we are calling it externally, is there any option to get within that transformation?